# pygame.font not working and not showing any errors also

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

Everything is working fine except that font thing, i don't know why it's happening and it's not even showing any error. And not displaying the Text on screen.

```
# import library here
import pygame
import time
import sys

# display init
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

# game initialization done
pygame.init()

# game display changed
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

# init font object with font size 25 
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def message_to_display(msg, color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [10, 10])

message_to_display("You Lose", red)
time.sleep(3)

pygame.quit()
# you can signoff now, everything looks good!
quit()
```

Comment: `red` in `message_to_display("You Lose", red)` has not been defined anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see nothing is because you haven't ***updated*** or ***'flipped'*** the display. After you've created the text Surface and blit it to the gameDisplay Surface you have to update/'flip' the display so it becomes visible to the user.

So, between `message_to_display("You Lose", red)` and `time.sleep(3)` you put `pygame.display.update()`or `pygame.display.flip()` (it doesn't matter which). Like this:

```
# import library here
import pygame
import time
import sys

# display init
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

# game initialization done
pygame.init()

# game display changed
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

# init font object with font size 25 
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def message_to_display(msg, color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [10, 10])

message_to_display("You Lose", red)
pygame.display.update()  # VERY IMPORTANT! THIS IS WHAT YOU MISSED!
time.sleep(3)

pygame.quit()
# you can signoff now, everything looks good!
quit()
```

Also, as *J.J. Hakala* pointed out, you have to define ***red*** in `message_to_display("You Lose", red)` as well.